# uploading file using input field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2019

I created a web app using `asp.net-mvc` and `Jquery`

when I added the below code my application automatically stop running without throwing any error, I don't know Whether it is my `visual studio 19` or `IIS` which is being crashed

```
<label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
```

To verify I created an `asp.net mvc` sample project and paste the above code in the index page but the same problem comes

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7SzT.png)

what can I do to solve this?

Comment: check error messages in chrome's console if there is any, please paste it here, to open console, right click inside browser and select "Inspect", then select console tab, check if there is any error when you select any file.

Comment: there is no error in chrome console i checked it in the first place only

Comment: Is your issue solved?If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal my issue is not solved, the problem is my code is working on my colleague's machine but not on my machine, but when I upload the application on `iis` it works, I think there is something wrong with my vs19 or other os setting

Comment: did you check the event viewer log?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

property in your form element?

Comment: We need more details in your code, what do you use in background while form is posted? What exception you get? What is actually happening ext.

Comment: Just select a file in input field and application stopped

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="upload">
<input type="file" id="file" class="form-control">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$('#upload').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission
            var File_Name = $("#file").prop('files')[0].name;
            var ext = File_Name.split('.').pop();
            if (ext == "pdf" || ext == "docx" || ext == "doc" || ext == "png" || ext == 
                 "jpg" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "txt") {
                var lastIndex = $("#file").prop('files')[0].name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append("file", $("#file").prop('files')[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Main/SaveDocument',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.UploadedFileCount + ' file(s) uploaded successfully');
                        if (data == "999") {
                            swal("Note", "Some Error Occurred. File Not uploaded successfully.", "error");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, error, status) {
                        console.log(error, status + " " + xhr);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                swal("Note", "File Type Not Supported.", "warning");
            }

        });
```

C#

```
public ActionResult SaveDocument()
        {


            //file
            var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

            var CheckCnic = hr_FTPEntities.File_description.Where(x => x.uploader_CNIC == userCNIC).FirstOrDefault();
            if(CheckCnic == null)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(file);

                if (filebase.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filebase.FileName);

                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(basePath + departmentName) + "/");

                    File_description file_Description = new File_description();
                    int fileCount = hr_FTPEntities.File_description.Select(x => x).ToList().Count + 1;

                    int lastIndexOfDot = fileName.LastIndexOf(".") - 1;
                    string finalFileName = fileName.Substring(0, lastIndexOfDot) + "_" + fileCount + fileName.Substring(lastIndexOfDot + 1);

                    file_Description.file_name = finalFileName.ToString();

                    try
                    {
                        filebase.SaveAs(path + (finalFileName));
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        return Json("999");
                    }

                }
                return Json("000");
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("888");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sir I am getting error while selecting a file into input field

Comment: Please Copy and paste the new formatted code and check if it works.SWAL user in JSON response is 3rd party jquery library you can use simple alert instead of this.

Comment: did it but still same issue when I select a file into input field

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below code:

View(Index.cshtml) :

```
            <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" />
            <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload Files" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnUpload').click(function () {

        // Checking whether FormData is available in browser
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

            var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            // Create FormData object
            var fileData = new FormData();

            // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }

            // Adding one more key to FormData object
            fileData.append('username', 'test');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                processData: false, // Not to process data
                data: fileData,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("FormData is not supported.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        // Checking no of files injected in Request object  
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //  Get all files from Request object  
                HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";  
                    //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);  

                    HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                    string fname;

                    // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                    if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                    {
                        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fname = file.FileName;
                    }

                    // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
                    fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                    file.SaveAs(fname);
                }
                // Returns message that successfully uploaded  
                return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("No files selected.");
        }
    }
```

Make sure your IIS site contains the upload folder and enough permission to access the folder.

[image]

If you still face the same issue then try to use the different browser.
check event viewer logs or try to collect the dup and analyze the dump using the DebugDiag tool.